# How to fix a Python nested loop to run faster?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, for-loop

I'm trying to write a piece of code that reads some rows from a worksheet (using openpyxl) and then create a list based on the data in the rows and a preexisting list (which is based on the same sheet). I created a loop that does the job, but is way too slow when it gets a bigger worksheet file. Is there a way to make it faster?

```
biglist = []

rows = #some rows extracted from Excel with openpyxl

lists = [[1, 'E1000', 0], #this is just a small sample
         [1, 'F1000', 0], 
         [1, 'G1000', 4], 
         [1, 'H1000', 3], 
         [1, 'I1000', 5],
         [2, 'E1000', 1]] 

for row in rows:
        for cell in row:
            smalllist =[]
            smalllist.append(1)
            smalllist.append(cell.coordinate)
            style = 0
            for l in lists:
                for i,cl in enumerate(l):
                    if l[i][0] == smalllist[0] and l[i][1] == smalllist[1]:
                        style = l[i][2]
            smalllist.append(style)
            smalllist.append(cell.value)
            biglist.append(smalllist)
```

What really slows down the loop is this piece:

```
            for l in lists:
                for i,cl in enumerate(l):
                    if l[i][0] == smalllist[0] and l[i][1] == smalllist[1]:
                        style = l[i][2]
```

Is there a way to speed it up? I've tried with map and list comprehension but it was not much faster, or it was even slower.

Comment: Why is `del l[i]` necessary? And `l[i]` can just be `cl`.

Comment: `del l[i]` is not necessary for the loop itself. It just cleans the pre-existing *lists* list

Comment: Your main code snippet doesn't match the one that you mention as being the culprit.

Comment: True. I've just edited it.

Answer (score 1):

You did not show what `styles` is, but you could try to build a mapping from it (mapping has almost linear lookup time), so you don't need to iterate over `styles` every time. This is, assuming that this part really is the bottleneck of your code (as you stated in the question).

You could build a `dict` before the loop:

```
styles_dict = {
    (cl[0], cl[1]): cl[2]
    for cl in s
    for s in styles}
```

And look up particular styles inside the look like this:

```
style = styles_dict.get((smalllist[0], smalllist[1]))
if style is not None:
    pass
```

Does that work for you?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Ralf's answer (which is the first obvious thing to do indeed), there are a couple more possible micro-optimisations:

First, do not create `smalllist` empty just to append to it, populate it directly instead (I assume you have implemented Ralf's solution) - this will avoid the cost of multiple method resolution and call - and then alias `biglist.append` and `styles_dict.get` (idem, avoids the cost of a constant repeated method resolution):

```
biglist = []
# local alias
append = biglist.append
get_style = styles_dict.get

for row in rows:
    for cell in row:
        # avoids a double lookup
        coords = cell.coordinate
        append([1, coords, get_style((1, coords), 0), cell.value])
```

Or write an helper function to create the "small list" and use a list comprehension:

```
def tranform(cell):
    coords = cell.coordinate
    return [1, coords, get_style((1, coords), 0), cell.value]

biglist = [transform(cell) for row in rows for cell in row]
```

You can use the `timeit` module to test which solution is faster.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `dict` to look up your styles, using the first two columns as the key:

```
styles = {(1, 'E1000'): 0, 
    (1, 'F1000'): 0, 
    ...}
```

Then look up and apply your style like so...

```
key = (smalllist[0], smalllist[1])
style = styles[key]
```

This should be fastser for large style lists as the lookup is constant time, instead of linear.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `dictionary` from the `lists` and lookup in the dictionary instead of looping over `lists` every time -

```
dict_keys = [(l[0], l[1]) for l in lists]
dict_values = [l[2] for l in lists]
dict_of_lists = { k:v for (k, v) in zip(dict_keys, dict_values) }
```

And you can replace the inner `for` loop with a lookup -

```
key = (smalllist[0], smallist[1])
try:
    style = dict_of_lists[key]
except KeyError:
    style = 0
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to:

1. import your worksheet as a Pandas dataframe
2. apply whatever filter you want to its rows and columns.

*Note:* In my experience you'll write much less lines of code and it'll run faster than a traditional for loop.

Comment: Blindly assuming that a panda-based solution will be always be faster than a handcoded one is just cargo-cult. You have to benchmark both solutions to know.